# Mongodb alternative to Dot notation to edit nested fields with $inc

Tags: mongodb

conceptually what I am trying to figure out is if there is an alternative to accessing nested docs with mongo other than dot notation.

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

I have a user collection, and each user has a nested songVotes collection where the keys for this nested songVotes collection are the songIds and the value is their vote form the user -1,0, or 1.

I have a "room collection" where many users go and their collective votes for each song influence the room. A single room also has a nested  songVotes collection with keys as songIds, however the value is the total number of accumulated votes for all the users in the room added up. For purposes of Meteor.js, its more efficient as users enter the room to add their votes to this nested cumulative vote collection.
Again because reactive joins in Meteor.js arent supported in any kind of efficient way, it also doesnt make sense to break out these nested collections to solve my problem.

So what I am having trouble with is this update operation when a user first enters the room where I take a single users nested songVotes collection and use the mongo $inc operator to apply it to the nested cumulative songVotes collection of the entire room.

The problem is that if you want to use the $inc operator with nested fields, you must use dot notation to access them. So what I am asking on a broad sense is if there is a nice way to apply updates like this to a nested object. Or perhaps specify a global dot notation prefix for $inc something like:

`var userVotes = db.collection.users.findOne('user_id').songVotes
 // userVotes --> { 'song1': 1, 'song2': -1 ... }
db.rooms.update({ _id: 'blah' }, { $set: { roomSongVotes: { $inc: userVotes } } })`

Comment: shouldn't it be something like update({ _id: 'blah' }, {$inc:{'roomSongVotes.userVotes': 1}}). I think there might be something wrong with the syntax of the query, but i'm not sure why you would need something other than dot notation. i think you can use [] like in js if the element name is not a regular variable name

Comment: yes you are correct, but if I have 50 or so fields I want to update that are all nested under the same parent field "songVotes", then I dont want to specify "songVotes.blah1",  "songVotes.blah2", ... - if I dont have to. It would be nice to be able to not have to use dot notation and simply specify a parent field for all of the sub-fields that I want to affect using $inc --- Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to use dot notation, but you can still do that in your case by programmatically building up the update object:

```js
var userVotes = {'song1': 1, 'song2': -1};
var update = {$inc: {}};
for (var songId in userVotes) {
    update.$inc['roomSongVotes.' + songId] = userVotes[songId];
}
db.rooms.update({ _id: 'blah' }, update);
```

This way, `update` gets built up as:

```js
{ '$inc': { 'roomSongVotes.song1': 1, 'roomSongVotes.song2': -1 } }
```